# Reasons why storing lists in cells in a Pandas dataframe is a bad idea?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, simulation

Im running some computational simulations (neuroscience) in python, and looking at ways to store the data for easy accessibility and organisation. I like pandas (despite the state of the documentation) for the accessibility of the .loc functions and the ability to use named indexes (makes things a lot more readable and understandable on revisiting old code).

My need is to store output data from multiple 'neurons' in different subpopulations (as a two level column multi-index subpop -> neuron), then have the rows represent different output variables (ie membrane voltage, spike train etc etc) with each cell being a list where the time series of the relevant variable is stored, and appended with each simulated step forward in time

My reasoning is this would make it very easy to access the specific output variables I want for a given neuron in a given subpopulation, as the idea is to run a lot of permutations of these simulations to explore the parameter space, which means generating a lot of data then doing batch analyses on the outputs of different parameter choices.

I have encountered people on threads saying it is a bad idea to use lists within dataframes, but without a clear explanation why. I am definitely at the novice end of the spectrum when it comes to programming, so could someone break it down for me as plainly as possible? Is it just an efficiency issue, or is it 'unsafe' in some way?

If its a totally bad idea, what are some alternatives that would preserve the qualities I'm looking for with dataframes & lists?

Comment: Basically pandas is a wrapper around numpy arrays and they are optimised for working with numeric data - storing non-numeric data in them negates any advantage of why you'd want to use them.

Comment: if you mean full list in single cell then it make no sense because pandas has no special functions to work with this. You should keep single value in single cell. The same problem could be with list in single cell in database because SQL has no special function to work with this. So in both situation list should be converted to row in pandas or database.

Comment: BTW: in databases this type of data s keep in separated table with foreign-key to original table and every value is in separated row - this way SQL can work with this.

Comment: Thanks guys. In hindsight I can see it was always a bad idea, and I could do a much better job just using the output variables as the 3rd level of the column multiindex, and time as the row index.

Thanks for the answers!